# Component config on load?

Tags: react.js

the problem being - On component loads, I have this statement which is essentially three flags that determine what is displayed on the page, is there a more elegant way to achieve this? it doesn't feel right checking the ordertype 3 times. I have trimmed down the component as much as possible.

```
function Component({ displayConfig, inputField, errors}) {
  let { type, heading, bodyText, inputHeader, inputHint } = displayConfig;
  
  const img = type === ORDER_TYPE ? PendingInvoiceGS : EmailerSettingsGS;

  const isNumberError =
    type === ORDER_TYPE ? errors.isOSNumber : errors.isPRDNumber;

  const isNumberInRangeError =
    type === ORDER_TYPE ? errors.isOSBetweenBounds : errors.isPRDBetweenBounds;

  return (
    <Component>
      {img}/{isNumberInRangeError} /{isNumberError}
    </Component>
  );
}
```

Comment: "I have trimmed down the component as much as possible." While Stack Overflow appreciates this, on Code Review we require the exact opposite. Please take a look at the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 2):

One option is to make an object for OS and PRD. I don't know enough about the domain to suggest names, so I've used "Whatsit" as a placeholder -- I suggest you replace that with something more meaningful in your context.

```
class Whatsit {
  constructor(img, isNumberError, isNumberInRangeError) {
    this.img = img;
    this.isNumberError = isNumberError;
    this.isNumberInRangeError = isNumberInRangeError;
  }
}

const osWhatsit = errors => new Whatsit(PendingInvoiceGS, errors.isOSNumber, errors.isOSBetweenBounds);

const prdWhatsit = errors => new Whatsit(EmailerSettingsGS, errors.isPRDNumber, errors.isPRDBetweenBounds);

function Component({ displayConfig, inputField, errors}) {
  let { type, heading, bodyText, inputHeader, inputHint } = displayConfig;

  const isOrderType = type === ORDER_TYPE;
  const whatsit = isOrderType ? osWhatsit(error) : prdWhatsit(error);

  return (
    <Component>
      {whatsit.img}/{whatsit.isNumberInRangeError} /{whatsit.isNumberError}
    </Component>
  );
```

You could go a step further and let Whatsit know how to render itself:

```
class Whatsit {
  constructor(img, isNumberError, isNumberInRangeError) {
    this.img = img;
    this.isNumberError = isNumberError;
    this.isNumberInRangeError = isNumberInRangeError;
  }

  // this needs a more domain relevant name
  asSlashSeparatedString() {
    return `${whatsit.img}/${whatsit.isNumberInRangeError} /${whatsit.isNumberError}`;
  }
}
// ... 

  return (
    <Component>
      {whatsit.asSlashSeparatedString()}
    </Component>
  );
```

Or, you could turn the class into a component:

```
const Whatsit = ({ img, isNumberError, isNumberInRangeError }) =>
  `${img}/${isNumberInRangeError} /${isNumberError}`;

// ... 

const osWhatsitProps = errors => ({ img: PendingInvoiceGS, isNumberError: errors.isOSNumber, isNumberInRangeError: errors.isOSBetweenBounds });
const prdWhatsitProps = errors => ({ img: EmailerSettingsGS, isNumberError: errors.isPRDNumber, isNumberInRangeError: errors.isPRDBetweenBounds });


// ...

  const whatsitProps = isOrderType ? osWhatsitProps(error) : prdWhatsitProps(error);

  return (
    <Component>
      <Whatsit {...whatsitProps} />
    </Component>
  );
```

You could maybe simplify it further if you can change the structure of your errors object into:

```
{
  ...,
  os: {
    isNumberError: "...",
    isNumberInRangeError: "..."
  },
  prd: {
    isNumberError: "...",
    isNumberInRangeError: "..."
  }
```

because then you can simplify your methods for producing your os/prd props. It becomes:

```
const osWhatsitProps = errors => ({ img: PendingInvoiceGS, ...errors });
const prdWhatsitProps = errors => ({ img: EmailerSettingsGS, ...errors });

// ... 

const whatsitProps = isOrderType ? osWhatsitProps(errors.os) : prdWhatsitProps(errors.prd);
```